# how to monitor the events of passing the volume key for long after lock screen in android?

Tags: android, volume, lockscreen

I want to add a listener on the event of pressing the volume key for long after locking the screen,but i do not know how to do it.who can tell me?

Comment: Your question is too general. You need to provide code for what you have already done.

Comment: I just begin to do it,and have not any code.I just want to know whether it is possible or not.For example,when I press the volume key for 3s ,my App or service will start and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible on the stock ROM.

Comment: why?then,what key events besides power key can we monitor after lock screen?

Comment: @user2676965 I don't know why, it's fundamental Android limitation. One hack you can use - play sound with 0 volume and listen to volume up/down events. This can't give you an ability to catch "long"-press, but it's still something. But I must warn you - it's REALLY battery-wasting way. As far as I know there is no other listeners in screen-off mode you can use.

Comment: Thank you!then ,if i want to monitor  user press the volume key 3 times in 3 second ,is it possible?

Comment: @user2676965 Yes it is. Just place somwhere(in preferences, for example) the first time user press the button and number of presses happened since that time. If the number is 3 and time is no more than 3 seconds - it's your case.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will try to do it.If i have other questions ,i will ask you again. Thanks !

Comment: @user2676965 you are welcome, please, vote up for the answer or accept it if it fits your question